# Creating a Dynamic Range in Excel for X Rows

Tags: database, excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I've constructed a function to interpolate between data points. The syntax is =Interpolate(reference cell, reference table).

I've got a table that looks like this:

```
MarkRun   MaturityDate  ZeroRate    DiscountFactor

5-May-15    5-May-15    0.006999933     1
5-May-15    6-May-15    0.0069999329    0.999980822
5-May-15    5-Jun-15    0.008996562     0.9992362
5-May-15    6-Jul-15    0.008993128     0.998473566
5-May-15    4-Aug-15    0.006344264     0.99830152
5-May-15    5-Nov-15    0.006912941     0.996521185
5-May-15    5-May-16    0.007104633     0.992901219
               ...           ...                 ...
```

Each MarkRun date represents a distinct curve. Every 64 data points, the next MarkRun date starts. At the first new date, the DiscountFactor equals 1. The dates goes from 5 - May - 15 to 11 - Aug - 15

I want to interpolate a value for every instance where there is one month between the MarkRun and MaturityDate for every MarkRun date. The goal is to make a new table like:

```
MarkRun         MaturityRate      ZeroRate 
5-May-15        5-Aug-15          0.006744264
6-May-15        6-Aug-15
7-May-15        7-Aug-15
8-May-15        8-Aug-15
```

To do this, I need to interpolate only for the rows corresponding to each MarkRun date.

So for the first row in the second table, the ZeroRate is interpolated from a reference table of the first 64 rows from the first table. The second row in the second table is interpolated from the next 64 rows in the first table, and so on and so forth.

How do I specify a range to interpolate these values? So far I've got:

`=Interpolate(J2,OFFSET($A$2,0,3,64,2))` where J2 is the reference cell. How do I extrapolate this to fill the rest of the second table?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this really different from your last question here? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32052891/5090027 Because you should really comment on the answers already provided there if you have further clarification.

Comment: yeah sorry, i wasn't sure whether i should comment there or start a new question - i guess the difference here is rather than using the same set of data to populate values as in the last question, i'm trying to re-specify the range every 64 points. do you think there is a way to adapt one of the answers from the previous question to accomplish this? i appreciate your help very much.